# How do I find the version of bash I am running?

Tags: command-line, bash

(learning bash)
I was trying to check the bash version so I typed `/bin/bash -v`.

That outputted a whole lot of text to the screen (contents of .bashrc, and other files sourced from it).

Could I have screwed up something (like overwriting some config files/setting incorrect environment variables etc.) due to that command?

I also can't find documentation on what the `-v` switch is for.

Comment: If you ran `bash -v` you invoked a new bash shell with verbose mode activated, so you will see verbose output for further commands (at the very minimum you'll see `printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`). To end the verbosity, type `exit` command - you will be back in the original non-verbose bash shell (or whatever shell you were in).

Comment: If you want the version of the "currently running" shell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on

Comment: How can I "link" another question here? (not just comment)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The `-v` parameter for bash stands for verbose, and instructs bash to print out as much information as possible about what it is doing. On startup, it will print out all the configuration it is reading in.

To print out the version information for bash, use `bash --version`.

Comment: Great! I also found the [list of switches for bash](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_62.html).

Comment: Alternatively, if you're already running a bash shell, you can output the content of the special BASH_VERSION variable. `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`. There's also a special array (BASH_VERSINFO) containing each version number in separate elements. `if ((BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 4)); then echo "Sorry, you need at least bash-4.0 to run this script." >&2; exit 1; fi`

Comment: typo, should be something like `[ "${BASH_VERSINFO}" -lt 4 ]` or `[ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -lt 4 ]`

Comment: Too verbose, much easier with http://askubuntu.com/a/899187/1004

Comment: The problem with this method is you cannot be 100% sure that any script, symbolic link, or any other kind of mess up configuration, who changed any environment variable at login. As I answered below, Ctrl+x Ctrl+v will show you exactly the bash version you're currently running, regardless of any environment variable.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this will tell you the version of `which bash` (located at `/bin/bash` on most systems), which may be different than the version that happens to be running in some prompt or script. (For example, a script started with `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` might use a different version). Other methods (documented in other answers) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 120):

When running bash (e.g. from `gnome-terminal`) you can check value of `BASH_VERSION` environment variable.

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.37(1)-release
```

If the value is empty, you are not running `bash`.

Comment: This is better than just running `bash --version`, because it confirms that you are currently running bash, not just that you have bash installed on your system.

Comment: +1 `bash --version` does not show the bash you are currently using.

Comment: Beware: A set `BASH_VERSION` does not ensure that you are running `bash`: `export BASH_VERSION; csh -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION $SHELL $shell'`, so `$BASH_VERSION` may be set in `csh` as well

Comment: @Tino well, you could do a `$SHELL --version`, but again SHELL might be overwritten (and all shell do not support the --version flag).

Comment: `$BASH_VERSION` is very strongly advised over `$SHELL --version`. Needing this on a Mac trying to make sure I'm not using the system's `bash` over a package managed (up to date) `bash` has `$SHELL=/bin/bash`, but is correctly configured and running my desired version. Can't give another upvote here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 45):

There's a key shortcut that instructs current shell information to show up:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

From `man bash`

```
   display-shell-version (C-x C-v)
          Display version information about the current instance of bash.
```

This is the best choice if you have messed with environment variables.

Answer (score 9):

No, everything is alright. From `man bash`:

```
   --verbose
          Equivalent to  -v.
```

It is just not as silent as usual. Try

```
--version
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

The usual `--version` may give you too much multi-line boilerplate so what I am using  is

```
bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Pawel's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/280225/301745)

Comment: @wjandrea This is different from [Paweł Nadolski's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/280225). It runs the command in a new `bash` shell. One way this is useful is that it doesn't need the shell currently being used to be `bash`. Another is that, even in `bash`, it's possible (though not *good*) to set `BASH_VERSION` to a different value. It can even be exported as an environment variable. Yet even after running `export BASH_VERSION=foobar`, the method given here works, since the new `bash` shell resets its own `BASH_VERSION` automatically before performing the parameter expansion that reads it.

Comment: @EliahKagan, in my updated & upgraded installed 16.04 LTS system installed from the 16.04.1 iso file, `bash --version` says `4.3.48(1)-release` and `apt-cache policy bash`says `4.3-14ubuntu1.2` and I have checked that the executable `bash` file comes from the package 'bash'. How should this be interpreted? There is a similar mismatch for `usb-creator-gtk`, and in that case the apt-cache output is correct. -- Can we conclude that the higher version number is the correct one (and someone forgot to update the other one)?

Comment: @sudodus A program's version number can be different from the version number of the APT package it comes in. That's what you're seeing here. `4.3.48...` is the version of Bash, `4.3-14...` is the version of the `bash` package.

Comment: @EliahKagan I forgot to mention before, thanks for correcting me! I appreciate the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

To only get the version and not the multiline text:

```
$ bash --version | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

Comment: Or: `bash --version | awk 'BEGIN{ RS="[ \n]"; FS="[ \n]" }s{ print $0; exit}/version/{ s=1 }'`