# Check if Bash version is >= given version number

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, versions

I need to test if Bash version number is >= to a specific number.  For example I have:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

In order to use associative arrays the bash version number must be >=4.

In my bash script I'd like to put in a one-liner test in the most elegant / efficient / readable way possible, but other approaches are also accepted.

Comment: Have you looked at the `$BASH_VERSION` and `$BASH_VERSINFO` variables?

Comment: @steeldriver No. That would be an acceptable answer in bash specific case if you'd like to post it. However for other cases the environmental variables may not be available.

Comment: By the way, related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/39309/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-bash-i-am-running

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy that is related to bash only. Although I'm looking for a bash one-liner or script / function checking the bash version number only is not the ultimate goal. A generic routine to check all programs by appending `--version` and testing the output was the original intention. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Version number formats vary wildly across programs. The way they report version details also vary wildly. It's simply not practical to ask for a way to check a random program's version. This question is too broad.

Comment: All the ones I've tested so far use the `--version` parameter and return the version number on the first line. If a person encounters a program that doesn't follow those rules they would write custom code. This question is about all the programs I've found that follow the rules, not about those that break them. For example **conky** uses `conky -v | head -n 1 | cut -d" " -f 2` to display version number.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix there are no rules. `ssh` and `dash` don't even know a `--version` option (ssh uses `-V` and dash has no option). Vim spreads the version information across multiple lines. Even in the outputs you have shown, the location of the version number varies.

Comment: @muru The developer would know by testing in shell which programs can be version tested with the script (see answer posted below). S/he knows certain programs will require extraordinary coding to derive the version and would not use the script. The perl script in the answer (when you follow links to Stack Overflow) can be adapted for programs with multiple version numbers too. The perl script is incredibly robust and the author is willing to enhance it for new scenarios.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that doesn't make your question any less broad. Limit your question to something sane. For example, asking to obtain the version from an arbitrary command is certainly a broad question (asked of its own, it would have been closed quickly, but here it's snuck in as a side question). Specify the version format.

Comment: @muru So something like "test version number when it can be obtained by `--version` parameter"?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no, even then the output of the command can vary a lot. Why mention the command at all? This question should be limited to comparing version strings, and of some given format.

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
$ [ "${BASH_VERSINFO:-0}" -ge 4 ] && echo "bash supports associative arrays"
bash supports associative arrays
```

`BASH_VERSINFO` is a readonly array variable whose members hold version information for this instance of bash. Since it was introduced with bash 2.0, it is likely supported by all bash versions you will encounter.  But, to be cautious, we include a default value of of `0` for any earlier version bash for which this variable is unset.

#### Extracting version information from other programs

You asked about LibreOffice, Python, kernel, etc.

LibreOffice produces version information that looks like:

```
$ libreoffice --version
LibreOffice 5.2.6.2 20m0(Build:2)
```

To extract the version number:

```
$ libreoffice --version | cut -d' ' -f2
5.2.6.2
```

For python:

```
$ python -c 'import platform; print(platform.python_version())'
2.7.13
```

To obtain the kernel version, use `uname`:

```
$ uname -r
4.9.0-2-amd64
```

Comment: Great answers! Just a note that your `uname -r` is "4.9.0-2-amd64" which could test greater than mine "4.11.1-041101-generic" with a regular bash test when in reality my version number is greater.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Python tools can accurately compare version strings. See [Compare version strings in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11887762/4518341)

Comment: John-- the python example can be shortened with `$ python --version` which returns `Python 2.7.12`. @wjandrea-- thanks for the link +1. Perhaps I could build a table of all called program names and minimal version numbers. Then pass the table to a modified copy of the `python` link you provided. Because only compiled Python can be called by `grub` you would think a binary exists to do this or its possible in shell.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of comparing version numbers, you could test directly for the feature itself. `declare -A` returns `2` (at least in Bash 3.2) if it doesn't recognize `-A`, so test for that (it also prints an error):

```
unset assoc
if ! declare -A assoc ; then
    echo "associative arrays not supported!"
    exit 1
fi
```

(`declare -A var` also fails if `var` is a non-associative array, so `unset` it first.)

While I don't really assume anyone's going to backport features in Bash, in general it's more appropriate to check for the features, not the versions. 
Even in Bash's case, someone might compile a version with only limited features...

---

The more general case of testing version numbers has two parts: 1) how to find the correct version number to test, and 2) how to compare it against another value.

The first is the more difficult one. Many programs tell their version number with a command line flag like `--version` or `-v`, but the output format varies and programmatically picking the version number may be difficult. Then there's the issue of possibly having several versions of the same program installed at the same time.

The second depends on some knowledge of the format of the version numbers. `dpkg` can compare [Debian-style version numbers](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) (which I think includes [semver](http://semver.org/) type versions as subset):

```
if dpkg --compare-versions 4.3.30 ge 4.0.0 ; then
    echo "it's version 4.x"
fi
```

Or, just to combine the above:

```
bashver=$( bash --version | sed -Ee 's/GNU bash, version ([0-9.]+).*/\1/;q' )
if dpkg --compare-versions "$bashver" ge 4.0.0 ; then
    echo "'bash' in your path is version 4.x"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for `dpkg --compare-versions` that prevents you from parsing manually. If someone wants to test kernel versions: `if dpkg --compare-versions "$(uname -r | cut -d'-' -f1)" ge 4.15 ; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi`

Answer (score 6):

There's couple ways to approach what you want to achieve.

## 1. Use $BASH_VERSION

It's sufficient  to just to see what's in `$BASH_VERSION` variable. Personally I'd use subshell like so:

```
$ (read -d "." version trash <<< $BASH_VERSION; echo "$version" )
4
```

Note that `<<<` syntax for here-doc is not portable, if you're going to use it with `/bin/sh`, which is Dash on Ubuntu and might be something else on a different system

Alternative way is via case statement or if statement. Personally, I'd do this:

```
bash-4.3$ case $BASH_VERSION in 4.*) echo "Can use associative arrays";; ?) echo "can't use associative arrays" ;; esac
Can use associative arrays
```

Probably for the sake of portability , you probably should check if such variable is even set at all in the first place with something like `[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]`

This totally can be rewritten as function to be used in a script. Something a long the lines of:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
version_above_4(){
    # check if $BASH_VERSION is set at all
    [ -z $BASH_VERSION ] && return 1
   
    # If it's set, check the version
    case $BASH_VERSION in 
        4.*) return 0 ;;
        ?) return 1;; 
    esac
}

if version_above_4
then
    echo "Good"
else
    echo "No good"
fi
```

This is not a one-liner, although this is much better. Quality over quantity.

## 2. Check what's installed

For that you need to filter output of `apt-cache policy` like so

```
$ apt-cache policy bash | awk -F '[:.]' '/Installed:/{printf "%s\n",substr($2,2)}'
4
```

`dpkg-query` can also come in handy with some filtering via `awk`.

```
$ dpkg-query -W bash | awk '{print substr($2,1,1)}'   
4
```

Note that this is not portable, since if there's no `dpkg` or `apt` installed on a system ( for instance, RHEL or FreeBSD ), it won't do you any good.

## 3. Use set -e to exit script if there's an error

One way to get around it is just simply go ahead an use associative arrays and quit when `bash` cannot use them. `set -e` line below `#!/bin/bash` will allow the script to quit if the script can't use associative array.

This will require you to explicitly tell the user: "Hey, you really need bash version 4.3 or above, otherwise the script won't work".  Then the responsibility rests with the user, although some might argue that this is not really a good approach to software development.

## 4. Abandon all hope and write portable, POSIX-compliant scripts

`bash` scripts aren't portable because its syntax isn't compatible with Bourne shell. If the script that you're writing is going to be used on a range of different systems, not just Ubuntu alone, then abandon all hope, and find ways to use something other than associative arrays. That might include having two arrays or parsing a configuration file. Consider also switching to a different language, Perl or Python, where syntax is at least more portable than `bash`.

Comment: The associative array is the second of "two arrays" as you suggest in section 4. It's sole purpose is to hold the key "path/to/file-name" and the value is the index within the main array. The associative array was created to speed up searches into the regular indexed array which are currently sequential. Although I have my eye on Python anyway, my current bash compatibility is focused on Ubuntu and perhaps Bash for Windows 10. I like your script which can be tailored. For example `yad --version` returns `0.37.0 (GTK+ 3.18.9)` but new features are currently in `0.39`.

Comment: great and helpful answer. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## One-liner not possible but a bash script is possible

I developed a script that draws on answers in Stack Overflow. One of those answers led to a Dell Employee writing version number comparisons in 2004 for the DKMS application.

### The code

The bash script below needs to be marked as executable using the command `chmod a+x script-name`. I'm using the name `/usr/local/bin/testver`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: testver
# PATH: /usr/local/bin
# DESC: Test a program's version number >= to passed version number
# DATE: May 21, 2017. Modified August 5, 2019.

# CALL: testver Program Version

# PARM: 1. Program - validated to be a command
#       2. Version - validated to be numberic

# NOTE: Extracting version number perl one-liner found here:
#       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817646/extract-version-number-from-a-string

#       Comparing two version numbers code found here:
#       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash

# Map parameters to coder-friendly names.
Program="$1"
Version="$2"

# Program name must be a valid command.
command -v $Program >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Command: $Program not found. Check spelling."; exit 99; }

# Passed version number must be valid format.
if ! [[ $Version =~ ^([0-9]+\.?)+$ ]]; then
    echo "Version number: $Version has invalid format. Aborting.";
    exit 99
fi

InstalledVersion=$( "$Program" --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' )
# echo "Installed Version: $InstalledVersion"

if [[ $InstalledVersion =~ ^([0-9]+\.?)+$ ]]; then
    l=(${InstalledVersion//./ })
    r=(${Version//./ })
    s=${#l[@]}
    [[ ${#r[@]} -gt ${#l[@]} ]] && s=${#r[@]}

    for i in $(seq 0 $((s - 1))); do
        # echo "Installed ${l[$i]} -gt Test ${r[$i]}?"
        [[ ${l[$i]} -gt ${r[$i]} ]] && exit 0 # Installed version > test version.
        [[ ${l[$i]} -lt ${r[$i]} ]] && exit 1 # Installed version < test version.
    done

    exit 0 # Installed version = test version.
else
    echo "Invalid version number found for command: $Program"
    exit 99
fi

echo "testver - Unreachable code has been reached!"
exit 255
```